# Activiti multi-instance sub process concurrent completion issue

Tags: java, alfresco, activiti, bpmn, flowable

Multi-instance sub process is set `isSequential="false"`, while sub processes are created in parallel without any issues, users are not able to concurrently complete (Rollback due to optimistic lock exception) the user task (defined inside the sub process). This is quite a common use case, else completing them in sequence take lot of time.  Issue, remains even if multi-instance is designed on user task itself instead of enclosing them in sub process. The optimistic locking is caused due to multi-instance in built variables concurrent update(e.g. `nrOfCompletedInstances` and so on), not because of any custom variable updates

Comment: If your goal is to have multiple instances of your sub process active in parallel, your isSequential flag must be "false" as setting it to true means task/sub process instances will be created "one at a time" until your completion condition/cardinality condition is met.

Comment: Typo error in the post, sub process and user task inside in created in parallel,  concurrent completion execution of tasks are not happening due to optimistic lock